# How to perform a $setIsSubset on MongoDB using C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, set

I am trying to use $setIsSubset operator in MongoDB.

[Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/expressions/#setissubset) says I should wrote this :

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
var result = myCollection.Find(x => x.ExternalKeys.IsSubsetOf(values)).ToList();
```

However, I got the following exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll
>
> Additional information: Unsupported filter:
>   {myCollection}{ExternalKeys}.IsSubsetOf(value(System.Int32[])).

ExternalKeys property is declared as `Hashset<int>`

I am using MongoDB 3.4 and C# Driver 2.4.4 which AFAIK are latest versions.

Comment: [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) is an "aggregation" operator. You cannot yet use this in a `.Find()` until [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/) is available with MongoDB 3.6. You want [`Aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_Aggregate__1.htm) here instead, and with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)

Comment: But really if you are simply asking *"all these values are present in this array field"* then what you really want is [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/). So it's not really clear what you are asking for, except that you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I want to filter out `mycollection` and get only documents for which there is at least one integer in `ExternalKeys` that match a item of `values` variable

Eg : `values = [40, 30, 20]
ExternalKeys = [10, 20] //OK
ExternalKeys = [500, 600] //not OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually want [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) here for *"at least one of"* `[40, 30, 20]` to match in the target array. This is done with [`AnyIn()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyIn__1.htm)

```
myCollection.Find(
  Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn( x => x.ExternalKeys, new[] { 40, 30, 20 } )
).ToList();
```

[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is not just for arrays but is essentially a list of possible values that can match a property. It's just that MongoDB treats an array as matching "any of it's values" as well.

So that's actually what you are looking for in what you are calling a "subset", since the target is a "subset" of what it is being compared to where any element intersects.

Comment: Thanks for your help.